# Hadoop No appenders could be found for logger (org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.MRAppMaster)

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

I was trying to run the Word Count mapreduce using eclipse, i created a java project and export it to jar then run it with hadoop.

This is the code:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URI;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;

import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.IntWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Reducer;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Counter;
import org.apache.hadoop.util.GenericOptionsParser;
import org.apache.hadoop.util.StringUtils;.


public class WordCount {

  public static class TokenizerMapper
       extends Mapper<Object, Text, Text, IntWritable>{

    static enum CountersEnum { INPUT_WORDS }

    private final static IntWritable one = new IntWritable(1);
    private Text word = new Text();

    private boolean caseSensitive;
    private Set<String> patternsToSkip = new HashSet<String>();

    private Configuration conf;
    private BufferedReader fis;

    @Override
    public void setup(Context context) throws IOException,
        InterruptedException {
      conf = context.getConfiguration();
      caseSensitive = conf.getBoolean("wordcount.case.sensitive", true);
      if (conf.getBoolean("wordcount.skip.patterns", false)) {
        URI[] patternsURIs = Job.getInstance(conf).getCacheFiles();
        for (URI patternsURI : patternsURIs) {
          Path patternsPath = new Path(patternsURI.getPath());
          String patternsFileName = patternsPath.getName().toString();
          parseSkipFile(patternsFileName);
        }
      }
    }

    private void parseSkipFile(String fileName) {
      try {
        fis = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileName));
        String pattern = null;
        while ((pattern = fis.readLine()) != null) {
          patternsToSkip.add(pattern);
        }
      } catch (IOException ioe) {
        System.err.println("Caught exception while parsing the cached file '"
            + StringUtils.stringifyException(ioe));
      }
    }

    @Override
    public void map(Object key, Text value, Context context
                    ) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
      String line = (caseSensitive) ?
          value.toString() : value.toString().toLowerCase();
      for (String pattern : patternsToSkip) {
        line = line.replaceAll(pattern, "");
      }
      StringTokenizer itr = new StringTokenizer(line);
      while (itr.hasMoreTokens()) {
        word.set(itr.nextToken());
        context.write(word, one);
        Counter counter = context.getCounter(CountersEnum.class.getName(),
            CountersEnum.INPUT_WORDS.toString());
        counter.increment(1);
      }
    }
  }

  public static class IntSumReducer
       extends Reducer<Text,IntWritable,Text,IntWritable> {
    private IntWritable result = new IntWritable();

    public void reduce(Text key, Iterable<IntWritable> values,
                       Context context
                       ) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
      int sum = 0;
      for (IntWritable val : values) {
        sum += val.get();
      }
      result.set(sum);
      context.write(key, result);
    }
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Configuration conf = new Configuration();
    GenericOptionsParser optionParser = new GenericOptionsParser(conf, args);
    String[] remainingArgs = optionParser.getRemainingArgs();
    if ((remainingArgs.length != 2) && (remainingArgs.length != 4)) {
      System.err.println("Usage: wordcount <in> <out> [-skip skipPatternFile]");
      System.exit(2);
    }
    Job job = Job.getInstance(conf, "word count");
    job.setJarByClass(WordCount.class);
    job.setMapperClass(TokenizerMapper.class);
    job.setCombinerClass(IntSumReducer.class);
    job.setReducerClass(IntSumReducer.class);
    job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
    job.setOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);

    List<String> otherArgs = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (int i=0; i < remainingArgs.length; ++i) {
      if ("-skip".equals(remainingArgs[i])) {
        job.addCacheFile(new Path(remainingArgs[++i]).toUri());
        job.getConfiguration().setBoolean("wordcount.skip.patterns", true);
      } else {
        otherArgs.add(remainingArgs[i]);
      }
    }
    FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path(otherArgs.get(0)));
    FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(otherArgs.get(1)));

    System.exit(job.waitForCompletion(true) ? 0 : 1);
  }
}
```

But i got this error:

[2024-03-30 03:00:40.440]Container exited with a non-zero exit code 1. Error file: prelaunch.err.
Last 4096 bytes of prelaunch.err :
Last 4096 bytes of stderr :
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.MRAppMaster).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.

I've tried searching for solution and see people saying to create a log4j.properties file but i dont know where to but it?
[Here is my project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F9nAJ.png)